# Diferencia entre el constructor y ngOnInit en Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

He estado viendo la documentación de angular 2 sobre los Lifecycle pero no me queda claro.

¿Cual es la diferencia entre el constructor y ngOnInit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El constructor se usa para tareas más ligeras.

ngOnInit es un hook especial destinado a tareas más "pesadas", como traer los datos del provider o cosas así. Angular recomienda dejar los constructores para tareas muy livianas, y el resto dejarlo para ngOnInit.

ngOnInit se invocará una sola vez (se supone que tras el primer onChanges, pero en la práctica se llama en la creación del elemento, como si se invocase al constructor en la creación de la clase).

Aqui https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html lo explican un poco más en detalle (en "*The ngOnInit Lifecycle Hook*")

Respecto al resto de hooks, onchanges y ondestroy no tienen mucha ciencia y son más o menos autoexplicativos. El resto está detallado en https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html